# Expected Distance of Closer of Two Random Points to center of Unit Square

Tags: pr.probability

Given two random points picked in the unit square, what is the expected distance from the center of the square to the closer of the two points?

The expected distance from the center of a square to a random point is known to be about 0.382597. I believe I have managed to calculate an approximate answer of 0.3015435, but all methods I have tried so far to calculate a nice integral have failed.

Comment: I'd rather answer this on MathStackExchange than MathOverflow.  Mathematica gives your first number as (Sqrt[2]+Arcsinh[1])/6, and I can get an answer for the second number too, but the code and the result are not pretty.